# @Autowire vs AplicationContext way of injecting

Tags: spring-boot, autowired

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("kafka")
public class KafkaController implements ApplicationContextAware {

    @Autowired
    KafkaConfig config;

    ApplicationContext context;

    @GetMapping("messages")
    public void getMessages() throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("Queue name is >>>>>>>>>>>>" + config.getQueueName());
        System.out.println("<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<"+ ((KafkaConfig)context.getBean("kafkaConfigBean")).getQueueName());
```

When I invoke the service multiple times it gives me the same queuename value in the log **"Queue name is >>>>>>>>>>>>"**, but a different value if I get it like this : `((KafkaConfig)context.getBean("kafkaConfigBean")).getQueueName()`

When I create bean I use `Math.random()` to produce different output.

```java
    @Bean("kafkaConfigBean")
    @Scope("prototype")
    public KafkaConfig createKafkaBeanConfig() {
        KafkaConfig conf = new KafkaConfig();
        conf.setQueueName("prototype" + String.valueOf(Math.random()));
        return conf;
    }
```

Why it's generating different value via `applicationContext` way but same when using `@Autowired`. Isn't scope "prototype" means creating new bean each time requested.
Why for each call to controller `@Autowire` is returning the same bean ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, you're defining a singleton bean of type `KafkaController` that contains the autowired field `KafkaConfig config;`.  Since the bean is a singleton, it is only created once, and so the `KafkaConfig` field value within it is only created once.  Making multiple requests using that same Controller uses that same `KafkaConfig` value, and so the queue name doesn't change.

In the second case, you're calling `context.getBean("kafkaConfigBean")` yourself explicitly, which causes Spring to create a new bean every time you call it, because you've defined that bean as being a "prototype".  As designed, each time it is created, it computes a different queue name.

If you were creating multiple `KafkaController` objects, each of them would contain a different `KafkaConfig` field value, each of which having a different queue name.

Comment: Correct, I added @Scope("prototype") on KafkaController and it started chaging value for @Autowired instance variable. -Thx

Comment: Glad I could help!